# how to get data as array of object in flow

Tags: visual-workflow, configuration, config

yesterday I had posted the question regarding the content-type:problem+json in which I dig in and was finally able to understand the real issue, I need to pass the data in the body like  this

```
"qualifications": [
    {"qualificationType": "GCSE or equivalent","subject":"English","grade":"5","weighting":"Desired"},
    {"qualificationType": "GCSE or equivalent","subject":"Maths","grade":"5","weighting":"Desired"}
],
```

now the problem is flow returns the data in form of an array of string, something like this

```
"qualifications": [
    "{\"qualificationType\": \"GCSE or equivalent\",\"subject\":\"English\",\"grade\":\"5\",\"weighting\":\"Desired\"}",
    "{\"qualificationType\": \"GCSE or equivalent\",\"subject\":\"Maths\",\"grade\":\"5\",\"weighting\":\"Desired\"}"
],
```

please some advice or help will be appreciated,

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

thanks to this below Article I was able to find a solution.

[anyone who faces the same issue can refer to this article](https://munawirrahman.medium.com/json-parser-in-salesforce-flow-380b46c86030)

In simple terms thanks to Munawirrahman's Article on Medium he actually said in his article that we can simply install JSON2Apex pkg to our salesforce org through which we can call an invocable method in flow which will indirectly help us to convert the data into JSON, he mentioned two points

> 1. Sometimes my JSON data can be so complex, that if I put my JSON to JSON2Apex, they’ll return explicit parse code which will be complicated for me to return the data to Flow as variable
> 2. I should add new piece of apex codes every time I want to parse new JSON data or integrate with new Rest APIs

this is the source URL for github repo :- [click here](https://github.com/munawirrahman/MultipleJSONParser)
or else you can simply install to your org

> You can install it here (don’t forget to change login to test. salesforce if you want to install in the sandbox):
> v.1.1 https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t2w000009F5Go
> v.1.0 https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t2w000009F5Gj

still, I recommend going through his article for a better understanding.

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question - that could help people with the same issue. However, link-only answers are discouraged and may be deleted. *(See: [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers))* Please edit your answer to add more information. *(From [How do I write a good answer?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer): "...please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link....")*

Comment: Thanks, @Moonpie for your response and will try to make my Ans as easy as possible so others can take the best from it

Comment: Appreciate you coming back and greatly improving your answer!